# How do you pass an environment variable to Solr running inside Docker when the environment variable only exists inside the container?

Tags: postgresql, solr, docker

I need to do a dataimport from a PostgreSQL container running inside docker to a Solr server also running inside of Docker.

In my `docker run` command I specify the `--link` option which creates the environment variable `$POSTGRESQL_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR` inside the solr docker container, and I need to pass this into Solr to use in my `solrconfig.xml` file.

I've heard that this is possible by passing JVM environment variables to the Solr startup command, but `docker run` starts Solr automatically. The only workaround I've found is doing something like:

```
docker run --name solr -d -p 8983:8983 --link postgresql --volumes-from solr_cores makuk66/docker-solr /bin/true
```

Starting the container with bin/true so it does nothing, and then

```
docker exec -it solr /bin/bash
```

to get into the container, finally running the solr startup command myself with the flag

```
-Dsolr.database.ip=$POSTGRESQL_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR
```

However this is an involved manual process, and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on the page [Taking Solr to Production](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production) you see

> The bin/solr script simply passes options starting with -D on to the JVM during startup. For running in production, we recommend setting these properties in the SOLR_OPTS variable defined in the include file. Keeping with our soft-commit example, in /var/solr/solr.in.sh, you would do:
>   SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime=10000"

So all you need to do is edit the SOLR_OPTS environment variable in `solr.bin.sh`.

It's a bit different for Docker because you don't directly have access to `solr.bin.sh`, but it after some trial and error, it was as easy as adding this to my Dockerfile.

```
RUN echo 'SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.database.ip=$POSTGRESQL_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR"' >> /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh
```

Then you can use it in the solrconfig.xml file as

```
${solr.database.ip}
```

An important thing to note is that you can call the JVM environment variable whatever you want as long as you make sure not to overwrite anything important. I could have called it

```
-Dsolr.potato
```

if I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `solr.in.cmd` file looks exactly the same as `solr.in.sh` which confused me on how to set variables there. In windows containers, the command to accomplish the same - from a dockerfile, would be:

```
RUN Add-Content C:\solr\bin\solr.in.cmd 'set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dsolr.database.ip=%POSTGRESQL_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR%'
```